# Allow pydantic models to have optionally null fields like in v1

Tags: sqlalchemy, fastapi, openapi, pydantic, openapi-generator

I recently upgraded from Pydantic v1 to v2.

Because of this, it made me update my model:

```py
# OLD MODEL
class Tag(BaseModel):
    id: int
    name: str
    color: Optional[str]  # We didn't used to need to set a default value


# NEW MODEL
class Tag(BaseModel):
    id: int
    name: str
    color: Optional[str] = None  # Now we do
```

The problem is that it updated the OpenAPI spec in a way that breaks other applications we have that generate code based off of this:

```yaml
# Old spec
Tag:
  title: Tag
  type: object
  required:
  - id
  - name
  properties:
    ...
    ...
    color:
      title: Color
      type: string
```

```yaml
# New spec
Tag:
  title: Tag
  type: object
  required:
  - id
  - name
  - color            # Uh oh! Now it's required!
  properties:
    ...
    ...
    color:
      title: Color
      anyOf:          # Uh oh! We've got a weird type! I don't want null!
      - type: string
      - type: 'null'
```

This is a problem, because now all of a sudden we're encouraging people to send us `null` values, which is completely different from sending no value at all (to my mind).

So, to get around this, I found I could update my model differently:

```py
class Tag(BaseModel):
    id: int
    name: str
    color: str = None  # No longer optional!

# Now the openapi spec is perfect, like it used to be.
# color is not required, and does not accept null.
```

But then I run into validation problems with the Response:

```
E fastapi.exceptions.ResponseValidationError: 2 validation errors:
E  {'type': 'string_type', 'loc': ('response', 'tag', 'color'),
E   'msg': 'Input should be a valid string', 'input': None,
E   'url': 'https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.5/v/string_type'}
```

Endpoint:

```
@app.get(
    "/tags",
    response_model=List[src.schemas.tags.Tag],
    response_model_exclude_none=True,
):
    # Endpoint code which returns an SqlAlchemy model
```

### The problems

The problem here is that I don't just have 1 endpoint. I have about 100 endpoints, and I don't want to write and maintain custom validators for all of them.

I want my OpenAPI spec that I generate with `app.openapi()` to be the same, and I also want to allow the endpoint to return null/none instead of a string.

That's why I tried `response_model_exclude_none=True`, but to no avail.

- I want to **avoid making the schema use `anyOf string/null`**
- I want my runtime response validation to work

---

## EDIT

One of the bigger problems here is that when a SqlAlchemy model with Null/None is transformed into the schema, it enforces that null value.

It's actually not so much the default value, as it is that SqlAlchemy has a None/null and it forces that field in, which overwrites the default, which would not be validated because of `validate_default` being set to False by default. But because SqlAlchemy overwrites the default null with a new null, it is registered as being set, and it breaks.

Comment: The proper way would be to update the script that generates your code.

Comment: It is unclear from your question if you need a "not required and nullable" or a "not required not nullable" field.

Comment: On your color definition, no need to use anyOf.  OpenAPI 3.1.x allows an array of types.  `type: ['string', null]`

Comment: @npk - I completely agree, but that's done by the `openapi-generator` external utility.

@DurandA - I actually don't mind if the user is allowed to send null or not. I suppose I'd prefer if they didn't?

Comment: @Addison Did you try setting `response_model_exclude_unset=True` in your route?

Comment: @DurandA - I found it wasn't actually the route that had the problem - The problem was long before the route ever had a chance to return a response.

It was when the Pydantic object was created, based on the SqlAlchemy object

Answer (score 1):

Here is how optional fields should be declared in Pydantic v2:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel

class MyModel(BaseModel):
    not_required_and_nullable: Optional[str] = None
    not_required_not_nullable: str = None
    required_but_nullable: Optional[str]
    required_not_nullable: str
```

This is hence correct to declare color with None as a default value:

```py
class Tag(BaseModel):
    color: Optional[str] = None
```

Now you need a way to exclude unset values from your response model. Rather than using `response_model_exclude_none`, you should use [`response_model_exclude_unset`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/response-model/#use-the-response_model_exclude_unset-parameter).

As a side node, if you need a way to use your `Tag` model to distinguish between an unset `color` and a null `color` you can use [`model_fields_set`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/dev/api/base_model/#pydantic.BaseModel.model_fields_set)/`__fields_set__` (because `my_tag.color` is `None` in both cases. This is done automatically by FastAPI when using using `response_model_exclude_unset=True` in your route.

Answer (score 0):

I think the new behavior is completely correct and improves upon the somewhat blurry definition in v1. If a value is truly optional it needs to have a default value defined. This is fully in line with Python's standard behavior. The annotation `Optional[str]` is equivalent to the more explicit `Union[str, None]`, which explicitly allows for `None` to be a valid value. The most correct solution I can imagine here is choosing a meaningful default value:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Tag(BaseModel):
    id: int
    name: str
    color: str = "red"
```

This should declare the field as not required and would not break the validation either. In addition you have solved the question, which default to use, when the field is not provided by the user.

So I would put in the work and define meaningful defaults.

I hope this helps!